# SRX chassis cluster over layer 2 network

Tags: juniper, redundancy, juniper-srx

I need to setup a chassis cluster between two SRX650s over a layer 2 network. I have found [an article](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB23995&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1394904965936) which is applicable to my situation.

But I do not understand some portions:

1. Please explain the logical scheme. Where are the interfaces located ( `ge-0/0/0`, `ge-0/0/1`, `ge-0/1/0`) which are mentioned in the configuration below (which side of the switch?)?

   ```
   set interfaces ge-0/0/0 mtu 9014
   set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching port-mode trunk
   set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members 4094
   set interfaces ge-0/0/1 mtu 9014
   set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching port-mode trunk
   set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members 4094
   set interfaces ge-0/1/0 mtu 9014
   set interfaces ge-0/1/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching port-mode trunk
   set interfaces ge-0/1/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members 4094
   ```

   SRX240--------EX2200-------EX2200------SRX240
2. Do I understand correctly, that the *Trunk* should be only between the two EX2200 switches? Between the SRX and switch should be two separated links (from interface `ge-0/0/1` (fxp1) and from any `ge-0/0/x` (fab), correct?

Comment: I don't think that the KB article is correct. I have no idea why you would need VLAN ID 4094, it works with any VLAN-ID (we have this setup exactly). You just set the MTU to a high value and deactivate IGMP snooping and you're good to go. Also why did you ask a separate question, you already asked http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6812/ha-links-passing-through-switch-links-are-fiber-optic/6813

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The article you're referring to is simply setting up a trunk between 2 switches.

> Please explain the logical scheme. Where are the interfaces located (
>   ge-0/0/0, ge-0/0/1, ge-0/1/0) which are mentioned in the configuration
>   below (which side of the switch?)?

The configuration samples in your question are placed on the interface connecting the two switches.

> Do I understand correctly, that the Trunk should be only between the
>   two EX2200 switches? Between the SRX and switch should be two
>   separated links (from interface ge-0/0/1 (fxp1) and from any ge-0/0/x
>   (fab), correct?

Your understanding is correct. Below is a slightly modified diagram.

```
SRX240--------EX2200=======EX2200------SRX240
          ^            ^            ^
          |            |            |
        Access       Trunk        Access
         Port         Port         Port
```

Comment: Fizzle, Hello!
As far as I know Trunk passes through a tagging traffic. i.e. different traffic pass through one link (trunk). why in the configuration of this article are three different physical interfaces (ge-0/0/0, ge-0/0/1,ge-0/1/0).What is the role of each of them?

Comment: @user3214034 In order for the devices to _appear_ to be on the same LAN segment, you have to have a layer 2 connection between them. I believe the reason for 3 different examples was to give an understanding of how to apply the commands at different port/PIC levels. Probably unnecessary, but it seemed like a beginners guide.

Comment: Good!But this configuration for the Control Data traffic strictly. About this i have known from article, which lanK pointed out to me (answer below). Besides control link there is Data plan traffic( interface fab on srx).I think Data Plan traffic should be placed into another Vlan.

Comment: @user3214034 Without knowing any specifics to your setup, I can't say whether or not it will work the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

When I completed SRX clustering across the EX's switches, I found the specific Juniper AppNote below quite insightful in gaining understanding of all the various requirements.

[image]

[SRX Series Servicer Gateways cluster 
Deployment across layer 2 networks](http://kb.juniper.net/library/CUSTOMERSERVICE/GLOBAL_JTAC/technotes/3500165-EN.pdf)